# How does this MIPS code test for endianness?

Tags: mips, endianness

```
li $t0 , 0xABCD9876
sw $t0 , 100($0)
lb $s5 , 101($0)
```

New to MIPS; So my understanding is,

`li` loads the value `0xABCD9876` into register `$t0`

This value is then stored into memory at address `($0+100)`

lb then copies the byte at address `($0+101)` into register `$s5`

But there's nothing in register `($0+101)` is there? `0xABCD9876` was stored in `($0+100)`, not `($0+$101)`. Lost at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is byte-addressed. Hence, `($0+100)` points at a single byte. When it is used with a `sw` or `lw` instruction, you are actually accessing not only `($0+100)`, but also `($0+101)`, `($0+102)`, and `($0+103)` (in other words, you’re accessing four bytes (one word) *beginning at* that address). By storing a word and then accessing a particular byte of it, you can determine which order the word’s bytes were stored in memory, and hence determine the processor’s endianness.

Comment: Whenever I use `sw` or `lw`, do I always access four bytes?

Comment: @izelkay: Yes. A word is 32 bits, and a byte is 8 bits, so a word is 4 bytes; every time you store or load a word, you’re going to be storing or loading 4 bytes.